# An interesting observation on the roots of certain polynomials

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, roots

Consider the following polynomial:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\text{prime}(k)x^{k-1}$$
where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\text{prime}(n)$ is the $n$th prime. The first few polynomials are:
\begin{align}
n=1&:\quad 2\\
n=2&:\quad 2+3x\\
n=3&:\quad 2+3x+5x^2\\
n=4&:\quad 2+3x+5x^2+7x^3
\end{align}
Consider the number of real roots of these polynomials. The first few number of real roots of these polynomials form the sequence $0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,...$. This alternating zeros and $1$'s pattern holds for all primes less than $1000$ (verified by @Quimey) I have two questions:

- Does this pattern always hold? Said in another way, is the number of real roots of the polynomial $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\text{prime}(k)x^{k-1}$ always equal to $(1 + (-1)^{n})/2$?
- Is yes, how can we prove it?

*Note:* Sorry if I missed something "trivial", I don't have much experience in mathematics.

Comment: It seems to be true for the first 1000 polynomials (checked in sage)

Comment: @Quimey Could you give us the code (in sage) or check whether the OP's statement holds true for the first 2000 polynonomials?
$$$$
PS: The OP receives a lot of upvotes, your comment is the key :).

Comment: @NN2 I made a mistake in my previous claim, I meant "polynomials with primes less than 1000", code is pretty simple though
```
R.<x> = PolynomialRing(ZZ)
p = 0
for i, q in enumerate(prime_range(5000)):
    p += q * x ** i
    # c = len(p.real_roots())
    c = pari(p).polsturm(-100,100)
    if 2 * c != (-1) ** (i + 1) + 1:
        print('FOUND: ', q)
```

Comment: @user well, it is. See the first bullet point. I will edit the question to add it to the other parts also.

Comment: @user if I am not wrong, that isn't true. What happens if the coefficients are the values of the prime counting function? I am not sure, maybe there is a mistake in my calculation.

Comment: @user This is not true, $1+10X+11X^2$ has real roots.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe You are correct. Obviously the gaps between the coefficients should not deviate too much. But for evenly spaced coefficients (e.g. $c_k=k+1$ this seems to hold - checked till $k=500$).

Comment: Just reporting an observation (confirming user's last remark): I've tried a few variants of the proposed sum with different sequences of coefficients. It seems the same phenomenon can be observed provided the sequence of coefficients is "well-behaved" (by that I mean, weakly increasing, with no "abrupt decelerations"). For instance, just $\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^{k-1}$, or $\sum_{k=1}^{n}kx^{k-1}$, or even $\sum_{k=1}^{n}F_kx^{k-1}$ (where $F_k$ is the $k^{th}$ Fibonacci number).

Comment: Do the derivatives of the $P_n$ with $n$ even have zeroes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pattern breaks down at $n = 2437$, where the polynomial has two real roots according to the following code in SageMath (which outputs `2`).

```
R.<x> = PolynomialRing(ZZ)
primes = primes_first_n(2437)
p = sum(np.array(primes)*np.array([x**i for i in range(len(primes))]))
print(pari(p).polsturm())
```

I think this is the smallest such $n$. I'm not sure why the sequence breaks there in particular; the prime gaps around $\text{prime}(2437)=21727$ don't look particularly special.

We can exclude an error in the software by checking the exact value of the polynomial at rational points near the two roots (thanks to Ivan Neretin for the suggestion). I used SymPy's Rational class, but this could also be done using Python's `int` type and multiplying by the largest denominator power in the polynomial to avoid fractions. The output of the code

```
import sympy
n = 2437
sympy.sieve.extend_to_no(n)
for numerator in [-9967, -9966, -9965]:
    x = sympy.Rational(numerator, 10000)
    print(sympy.functions.sign(sum([sympy.sieve[i+1]*x**i for i in range(n)])))
```

is `1, -1, 1`, which proves that the polynomial has at least two real roots (by continuity).

Comment: Can you exclude an error in the software?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the implementation of the polsturm procedure, so I can't exclude an error. Perhaps someone with better knowledge of pari can help here? It seems unlikely given that the software does follow the pattern for values before and after $2437$ for a while, and then finds other values where the pattern breaks (for instance at $3379$ and $3383$).

Comment: I upvoted this. Nice answer, but I can't accept it till you are sure that there was no error in computation.

Comment: From the name `polsturm` I would assume the Sturm's polynomial sequence is computed and if the computation uses machine numbers instead of rational ones rounding errors are possible.

Comment: W|A also appears to give (at least) [two roots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B588b.png) for $\sum_{k=1}^{n=2437}{p_k \cdot x^{k-1}}$ with ``graph sum_{k=1}^{2437}{prime(k)*x^(k-1)} from -0.9967 to -0.99658``.

Comment: I've added @LinearChristmas' helpful comment in my answer, which gives further evidence that the polynomial really has at least two roots using WolframAlpha. This still doesn't fully exclude numerical approximation, but what would?

Comment: Check some rational number between the roots. Integer calculations don't lie.

Comment: Did it myself. $x=-{299\over300}$, the value is negative. Now that's something to think about.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my answer which should now be complete!

Comment: It is claimed that [`PARI.polsturm()`][1]'s results are "guaranteed" if the polynomial's coefficients are integers. And SageMath's prime list generated by [`primes_first_n()`][2] seems to be using an integral type (it would be somewhat strange to use anything else, wouldn't it?)


  [1]: https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/Polynomials_and_power_series.html#polsturm
  [2]: https://git.sagemath.org/sage.git/tree/src/sage/rings/fast_arith.pyx#n48

Comment: @Anselm678 Just checking whether you saw my updated answer? I excluded an error in the software following IvanNeretin's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This question motivated the following paper by W. Edwin Clark and Mark A. Shattuck which may be of some interest to fans of this question:
[The Integer Sequence Transform $a \mapsto b$ where $b_n$ is the Number of Real Roots of the Polynomial $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \cdots + a_nx^n$](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.05572)